# magento 2 how to add magestore slider in blog phtml file

Tags: phtml, blog, banner-slider

Here I have a blog page there I wanted to display banner sliders.
I configured the sliders they working fine in home page, but am unable to add in custom phtml(blog) page
here is my blog Phtml file

```
<?php
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\SliderItem")->setSliderId(3)->toHtml();

    $blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Mageplaza\Blog\Block\Listpost');
    $blockImageResize= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Mageplaza\Blog\Block\Frontend');


    // $coll =  $blockObj->getPostCollection();


?>
<div>
    <?php
    ?>
</div>
<div class="mp-blog-rss">
    <a href="<?= $block->getRssUrl('post/rss') ?>" class="bb-rss-icon">
        <img src="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl('Mageplaza_Blog::media/images/rss.png') ?>" width="16px">
    </a>
</div>
```

What am doing wrong? can i get help? Thank you.

Comment: Is any errors in console? where is the code for slider in this file?

Comment: @jafar pinjar Thank you for response. I added Extension of magestore banner slider. I configured in admin->Configuration. here inserting by `$this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\SliderItem")->setSliderId(3)->toHtml();`

Comment: yes that's fine, so you added other extension for blog also?

Comment: yes for blog i used Mageplaza Blog extension

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please! Change your code

**From**

> $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\SliderItem")->setSliderId(3)->toHtml();

**To**

> echo
>   $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\SliderItem")->setSliderId(3)->toHtml();

**Hope this will help you!!**

Comment: Thats a small miss, Thank you very much @jafar pinjar

Comment: Happy to help!!